# Finding Google's indexed pages

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

How do I find out how many pages Google has indexed on my website? I know I can just Google `site:http://foo.com`, but I would like to record the data and not have to do it by hand. Is there an API for pulling this data?
This is the number I want:

[image: Google search: site:apple.com]

I don't want the number of links, I want the pages indexed.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a site: search wouldn't necessarily show you everything, anyway. That only shows a sub-set of whatever it'd return. You get this information in Webmaster Tools. (This would additionally tell you if there are any particular problems with indexing you.)

Comment: Where in Webmaster Tools do I find the pages indexed?

Comment: @daviesgeek  - webmaster tools only tells you the number indexed. It won't tell you which pages.

Comment: @JMC I know, but where do I find that number?

Comment: You have to submit a sitemap. Once the sitemap is indexed it will tell you the number of pages indexed from the sitemap. If it's not on the sitemap it doesn't count toward that number.

Answer (score 0):

You must use : http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/ and the other option is check webmaster tool Open webmaster tool > Your site on the web > Links to your site.

Comment: I don't want to know the links to my site. See my revised answer.

Comment: Ok then you can use : http://www.searchenginegenie.com/allsites-total-pages.html and http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/indexed-pages/ tool

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thoroughly read through the docs, but as far as APIs go I think Google's custom search API is your best bet (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) this replaced their web search API which did have the functionality you're looking for.